# Why are there 2 different ComponentActivity classes?

Tags: android, androidx, android-ktx

I'm trying to handle back button presses in my fragments by registering an `OnBackPressedCallback` via `addOnBackPressedCallback` to receive `onBackPressed()` callbacks without needing to override the method in your activity (described [Nov 5, 2018 release notes for androidx.activity](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity))

If you look at the [AppCompatActivity Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity), it claims `AppCompatActivity` extends from `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`.

The problem I'm running into is, in my codebase, `AppCompatActivity` extends from `androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity` (doesn't have `addOnBackPressedCallback()`) instead of `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity` (has `addOnBackPressedCallback()`).

My Dependency Versions

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0-alpha04"
```

Can anybody else reproduce this issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity` is a hidden class that was used prior to `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity` being created as part of AndroidX Activity 1.0 and Fragment 1.1.0

You need to switch to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02` to pull in Fragment 1.1.0, which changes `FragmentActivity` (and hence, `AppCompatActivity`) to extend `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`