# Androidx Activity OnBackPressedCallback Interface Issue

Tags: android, android-activity, androidx, android-ktx

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04")
implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2")
implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0-alpha05")
```

I was also looking at this [Why are their 2 different ComponentActivity classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915164/why-are-their-2-different-componentactivity-classes/54915331#54915331)
I have this library setup and hoping to use **OnBackPressedCallback**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

open class BaseNiceFragment : Fragment(), OnBackPressedCallback {

    override fun handleOnBackPressed(): Boolean {
       // do some nice things here
       return true
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
       activity!!.addOnBackPressedCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, this)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
       super.onDestroyView()
       activity!!.removeOnBackPressedCallback(this)
    }

    protected open fun handleEmptyView(isListEmpty: Boolean) {} 
}
```

It works fine with debug builds with Android Studio but whenever I try to do a `app:compileFullReleaseKotlin`, I keep running into the following issues

```
BaseNiceFragment.kt: (_, _): Unresolved reference: OnBackPressedCallback
```

Anyone or Ian know how to make sure this is included in all of my builds

```
public interface OnBackPressedCallback {
 //...
}
```

Comment: You call, I answer ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're mixing stable releases (`appcompat:1.0.2` and the `fragment:1.0.0` it depends on) with alpha releases. Only Fragment `1.1.0` alpha versions of `FragmentActivity` depend on `androidx.activity`'s `ComponentActivity` and therefore include the `addOnBackPressedCallback` method.

You need to specifically include `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha05` or switch your AppCompat dependency to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03` (which transitively depends on Fragment `1.1.0-alpha05`).

Comment: If this answered your question, make sure to accept the answer to remove the question from the queue of unanswered questions

Comment: @ianhanniballake `addOnBackPressedCallback` is gone in 1.1.0-alpha08. What should I use ?

Comment: @vovahost - as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back), you should use `getOnBackPressedDispatcher()` and the methods available on that class.

Comment: This is so confusing... I just want to try out some of the fancy new stuff you showed at Google IO and end up trying out dependencies the whole day. In my case it was `lifecycleScope` which somehow needed `Cancellable` which somehow lead to this error after I've put in some random dependencies out of the hundreds available in the ktx cyberspace. The chosen ones can even have a `-ktx` suffix which may contain just the functionality you want - just try it out.

Answer (score 4):

As of August 2019 this is all I needed instead of loading other dependencies as the top answer `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01`

Comment: Thanks. Finally a concise, non-confusing answer that works